Non-empty are dense iff the space is irreducible
I'm trying to show that the space is irreducible if and only if all of its non-empty open subsets are dense. I do understand how to show that if it is irreducible, then the any open subset other than $\varnothing$ is dense. However, I don't quite understand how to deal with the other direction.
I'm trying to do it by contradiction. Suppose that $X$ is not irreducible, while all of its non-empty open subsets are dense. Then there exist such proper closed $A\subset X$ and $B\subset X$ that $X = A \cup B$. Then $A^{\complement}$ and $B^{\complement}$ are open, moreover $A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement} = \varnothing$. Also we have that $\overline{A^{\complement}} = \overline{B^{\complement}} = X$. However I don't see how it contradicts with the fact that $X$ is reducible.

Well, if $A^c\cap B^c=\emptyset$ then it already means $A^c$ is not dense. (since it doesn't intersect the nonempty open set $B^c$)

@Mark thanks! Makes sense

This question is similar to: Show that $X$ is a irreducible topological space. Found using the search engine: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=non-empty+open+subsets+are+dense+irreducible

@AnneBauval yeah! missed this one! the proof is a little different, but also works, thanks!
